# nodejs how to scope parent object to mysql query anonymous callback

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm new to node.js and not yet fully into scoping of anonymous functions. I declared a object with several methods. Inside my method I first get a mysql connection from mysql pool and than do a query on the connection. Now I want to call a method of my object. After reading into scoping and binding i came to the following code as result.

I was wondering whether the following is bad practise or good and if there are any better patterns to achieve this?

```
function myclass() {}
myclass.prototype.dosomthing = function () {}
myclass.prototype.init = function() {
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection)){
        this.dosomthing();
        connection.query("sql_statement", function(err,rows){
            this.dosomething();
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Thx, I really appreciate your expertise!

Comment: Maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ could be better place to ask this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is fine, although it does involve creating unnecessary function objects (`bind` creates and returns a new function).

As an alternative, just use a variable you close over:

```
function myclass() {}
myclass.prototype.dosomthing = function () {}
myclass.prototype.init = function() {
    var self = this;                                   // Remember `this`
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection)){
        self.dosomthing();                             // Use it
        connection.query("sql_statement", function(err,rows){
            self.dosomething();                        // Use it
        });
    });
};
```

I've used `self` above, but generally I pick a name based on what the object actually is. So for instance, if `myclass` were `Foo`, I'd probably use the name `thisFoo` or similar.

---

Side note: The *overwhelming* convention in JavaScript is that functions meant to be used as constructors are named with an initial uppercase character. So `MyClass` rather than `myclass`.